# How do I view the page source in Safari just like I can in Windows Internet Explorer?

Tags: macos, safari, html

I'm experienced with Windows, not so much with Mac. In Windows Internet Explorer I can go to the View menu and select Source as in to “view source”. This opens a window showing me the html code of the page I am visiting, just like in the screenshot below:

[image]

On my Mac I looked in Safari's View menu and all the other menus and do not see anything resembling this option.

**How can I do the same thing on Safari in macOS?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The option is available in Safari, but it’s not on by default. To activate this, follow the steps below:

1. Launch Safari
2. Go to Safari > Preferences (or just use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> shortcut)
3. Click on the Advance tab in the Toolbar (it *should* be the last one)
4. At the very bottom tick the checkbox for *Show Develop menu in menu bar*
5. Exit the Preferences window

Now you’ll see a new Develop menu in the menu bar. This will give you access to a whole heap of options, including **Show Page Source**. It may be worth you exploring the various options to see what else you can make use of.

**[EDIT]**

I forgot to mention, once you've enabled the Develop menu, you will be able to also right-click on any page and choose *Show Page Source* from the menu that appears.